# ASP.NET MVC partial control

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to mvc. I have done a fair bit of development with Winforms and now I am working on an MVC project. In our winforms project we have standard controls such a dropdown list control which will show all employees. This control knows how to get the employees and display them. It exposes a property which gives the selected employee. The forms just need to put this control on it and use it.

Now my question is how can I achieve this in aps.net MVC (in views). I tried partial views but then how can I expose the selected value to the parent view

Comment: Trying to do things in the same way as Winforms is going to be frustrating. The web is a very different beast. Try an embrace the differences rather than try to make MVC work like you are used to. Have a look at the videos on the right of the asp.net/mvc page.

Answer (score 1):

In MVC, `Views` should not contains any logic other than display logic.

The `Controller` should be the one that "knows how to get the employees" or create an employee `Model` which will then pass to a `View` that knows how to display an employee, in most cases, it would be a strictly-typed `View` of type `Employee`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

Say, in your Model, you have an Employee (or list of, either or):

```
Employee Employee { get; set; }
```

So, your main View should have this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Employee);
```

But, how do I template this, you ask?

You should take a step back at this stage and consider making a new ViewModel, an EmployeeViewModel (this, in your mind, should be your "partial view").

So now you'll have:

```
EmployeeViewModel Employee { get; set; }
```

Now, create a folder in your Views/Shared called DisplayTemplates and create EmployeeViewModel.cshtml. To be clear, you'll now have /`Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/EmployeeViewModel.cshtml`.

The top line of this should read:

```
@model YourNamespace.EmployeeViewModel
```

And now you can simply use in this View:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeName) // or whatever properties you have
```

That should be sufficient enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

PartialView will be fine to you. so search some content by the keyword 'PartialView'