# IEnumerable property is null after submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC and have some difficulties understanding this.

To make it simple, I have a "Person" object and this object has an IEnumerable property  called "EmailaddressList".

I have generated an edit page through Visual Studio 2012. The main objects properties, are generated on the edit page with textboxes like Name and LastName.

However the list of e-mail addresses in the IEnumerable list of sub-objects are not generated automatically in my view.
This is OK, I have written that code by hand using a tab for each type of e-mailaddress.

So far so good.

**Problem:**
When I recieve the model (person object) in my HTTP-Post method, the EmailAddressList is null.
Why is it like this, It was not null when I sent it to the view.
I the tab where the e-mailadresses are listed is in a partial view.
Can anyone give me some tips, is it something I'm missing here?*

**View-Code**

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model.EmailAddressList)
    {
        <li><a href="#@item.AddressType">@Html.Label(item.AddressType)</a></li>
    }
</ul>
@foreach (var item in Model.EmailAddressList)
{
    <div id="@item.AddressType">
        <p>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(s => item.EmailAddress, new { @class = "input-xxlarge" })
        </p>
    </div>
}
</div>
```

**Controller (recieving method)**
Here person.EmailAddressList is null

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
            personRepository.InsertOrUpdate(person);
            personRepository.Save(); 
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        } 
        else 
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show some code please. Also are you certain these are identical -> "EmailaddressList" and "EmailAddressList"

Comment: Sounds like a binding problem, without code can't really tell you much else.

Comment: I have included some code in the original post.

Comment: Possible hints over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832888/modelbinding-ienumerable-in-asp-net-mvc-post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because in order to correctly index your fields (so model binder can do it's work), you have to use a `for` loop.

First, change your `IEnumerable` to be a `List` (so we can use an indexor in the view).

Then change your `foreach` to be the following `for` loop:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.EmailAddressList.Count; i++)
{
    <div id="@Model.EmailAddressList[i].AddressType">
        <p>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddressList[i].EmailAddress, new { @class = "input-xxlarge" })
        </p>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! And I guess it makes sense too.

Comment: @PeterLarsson No problems, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your update, the reason this doesn't work is because the default model binder only relies on order for a collection of *simple* data. When it comes to complex type you need to provide the relevant index per item otherwise it doesn't know which item property your referring to e.g.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.EmailAddressList.Count; i++) {
    Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddressList[i].EmailAddress) %>
}
```

See Phil Haack's article on [model binding to a list](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It's due to your elements not being ID'd the correct thing for MVC to pick them up on the post back, what you need is:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddressList);
```

Then, please refer to my post located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035759/asp-net-mvc-partial-control/16036361#16036361) on how to make this look to how you want it to.